# Replacing all the numbers with their currency format in given line of text

Tags: shell, string, sed, awk, number-formatting

I want to write a Shell (AWK, Sed also fine) program to take as a input a SINGLE line of text.

Which will have arbitrarily spread integer strings in it. e.g

"12884 and 111933 are two numbers and 323232 is also a number"

I want the output to be

"12,884 and 1,11,933 are two numbers and 2,23,232 is also a number"

If this was PHP a simple preg_replace_callback would have served the purpose but I want this to be in shell. :/

Any pointers would of great help.

Comment: For those who might be unfamiliar, the positions of the commas in this question are correct in India (they are not typos). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousands_separator#Examples_of_use

Comment: yes, they are not typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to split the line using `tr`. You can make use of Bash's word splitting feature:

```
line="12884 and 111933 are two numbers and 323232 is also a number"
for word in $line
do
    if [[ $word = *[^0-9]* ]]
    then
        printf "%s " $word
    else
        printf "%'d " $word
    fi
done
```

I've also used globbing to test for a sequence of digits rather than relying on something that creates an error or not depending on whether it's an integer.

Comment: Did not know of the word splitting feature, thanks for pointing that out. +1.
I think you have to correct that $foo var in the if test condition :P

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in $(echo "12884 and 111933 are two numbers and 323232 is also a number" 
    | tr ' ' '\n');
    do 
        if [ $line -eq $line 2> /dev/null ]; 
            then printf "%'d\n" $line;
        else 
            echo $line; 
        fi; 
    done | tr '\n' ' '
```

I understand this may be long and ugly but by now is the best I could do, I hope it will help.

Follows the explanation:

- fist I split the line on more lines so I can loop and recognize which strings are number and which are not
- then I test if the current string is a number
- if it is a number I parse with the usage of printf
- if it is not I simply echo it, leaving as it was
- finish the loop and put everything back on one line

Comment: "finish the loop and put everything back on one line"
I do not think this ie being done properly in my case.

I get '\n' printed in the line output

Comment: My solution is indeed a bit messy, I used it on only one line and worked as expected, @Dennis Williamson's is much clearer. Use his